# PyInstaller and skimage: ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, pyinstaller, scikit-image

After using pyinstaller on a python script I get this error when I try to execute the generated binary file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File ".../build/help_scan/out00-PYZ.pyz/skimage.io", line 59, in <module>
  File ".../build/help_scan/out00-PYZ.pyz/skimage.io", line 43, in _update_doc
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

The error comes from the line @15:

```
from skimage import io, color
```

I think that something goes wrong with the scikit-image library. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I copied the folder "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/skimage" into the folder with the binary file of my script. It seems to work.

I also tried to create a setup.py file for pyinstaller including the skimage library but It didn't work.